# how to upload videos in telegram via api that do not need to be downloaded in full

Tags: python, telegram

I have developed a bot that uploads videos to tg. Since most of the videos are large - I use the local API server in Telegram.

I download all the videos without problems, but to watch them, you need to download them completely, which sometimes takes too long
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2yNb.png)

Now I tried to upload videos using their ID, which is given to them during the initial upload. I hoped that these videos would be processed on tg servers and would be cached, but again, when sending them via ID, they still need to be downloaded in full.

I often see similar large videos on other channels, but you don’t need to download them to watch them

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JL4O.png)

How can you achieve the same opportunity for your videos so that you can watch them without having to download them completely?

I upload a video file like this:

````
        with open(local_video_path, 'rb') as video:
            start_upload_video = datetime.now().time()
            message = await bot.send_video(chat_id=properties.CHAT_ID,
                                           video=InputFile(video),
                                           duration=duration,
                                           read_timeout=300,
                                           write_timeout=300,
                                           connect_timeout=300)
            video_id = message.video.file_id
        end_upload_video = datetime.now().time()
    except BaseException as ex:
        print(f"Exeption: {ex}. Time: {datetime.now()}")
        pass```
````

or send a video by id like this:

````
```async def main():
    bot = Bot(token=TOKEN, base_url=properties.TG_LOCAL_API_SERVER)
    await bot.send_video(chat_id=CHAT_ID, video="id my video")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
````

all my expectations are described above